# ASP.NET Webform with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an application that was created on Visual studio 2008 using ASP.NET Web form technologies (3.5). The application has grown time by time and still being run on the same technology. The application has multiple sub-application that represents multiple areas of the application. These sub-application were created with the help of this [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2006/07/01/652986.aspx).

```
So just to give you a large picture of my entire application, it's:

SolutionFolder  
--- Application1
------- Application1_WebForm 
------- Application1_Code 
--- Application2
------- Application2_WebForm 
------- Application2_Code 
--- RootApplication  
------- RootApplication_WebForm 
------- RootApplication_Code
```

> MVC Application

```
--- Application3
------- Application3_MVC
------- Application3_Code
```

RootApplication contains the landing page of the application, also has all the shared components includes master page (contains navigation to other application folder), style sheets, scripts files and more. All these projects are built in webform technology.

Now, I would like to add one more application, lets say `Application3` which I would like to create using MVC.

I have added a new project with MVC and transformed the MVC application same way as my previous Webform application were made ( as provided in the example above).

When I try to access my `Application3` from the landing page in `RootApplication` I recieve the error shown below:

```
Server Error in '/ver3' Application.
The view 'Index' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx

Source Error:


Line 17:             HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
Line 18:             IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
Line 19:             httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
Line 20:             HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
Line 21:         }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the URL you are using to try to access Application3 ???

Comment: So my root url is http://localhost/Application/Shared/index.aspx. A link is created from this page, which redirects the request to particular application. So to access Application3, I am using http://localhost/Application/Application3/            I hope I am able to answer your question.

Comment: Remember, ASP MVC is going to look in your controller code to find out which VIEW to open.   You need to call a method in your controller.  Based on the error, it found the method Index(), but couldn't find the view.   What is VER3?  Where did that come from?

Comment: ver3 is my application root. in my example localhost/Application/Shared/Index.aspx... Application is ver3

Comment: @Sparky: So you think it would be my URL Routing issue?

Comment: I suspect so.   The message you got indicates it found the method in the controller and when it went to search for the view to display, it couldn't find it.   Try removing the /Shared from the path...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94717/discussion-between-fais-and-sparky).